# MediaRecorder audio wont play back on computer

Tags: android, audio

I am recording audio on the android device and it will play on the device but not on the computer.  I feel like its something to do with the path I give it.  In the path I specify a file extension.  I have tried no extension and .3gp(with the appropriate output format set) but it wont play on the computer.  Can anyone shed some light on this?

VLC gives the following error

> No suitable decoder module:
>   VLC does not support the audio or video format "samr". Unfortunately there is no way for you to fix this.

```
// Set up sound recording
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    path = "/sdcard/prism/sound/";

    // Make sure the directory we plan to store the recording in exists
    directory = new File(path);
    directory.mkdirs();

    recorder.reset();

    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
    recorder.setOutputFile(path + username + "_" + taskId + ".mpeg4");// + ".mp3");

    //Sometime later after button presses recorder.prepare() and recorder.start() are called
    // then after stop is pressed recorder.stop() and recorder.release() are called
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the best solution but I am using AMR Player to convert the .amr files to .mp3.

http://www.amrplayer.com/

If someone has a better solution please answer the question and I will accept your answer instead of mine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with your app but with VLC, it just doesn't support AMR. How about you try recording in AAC?
mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(3);